# How to view extended objects/arrays in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I have array of objects, when I type the name of variable in Chrome console, I get this:
[image]

**QUESTION:**
Is there some option or a flag which when turned on would display the objects and arrays extended when queried in Chrome console ?

I use the console a lot and do inline operations within the console and each time when I modify an array I have to click on all entries to see the values.

**I do not want** to write a loop which would `console.dir` out all the arrays.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To see the entire contents of an array (or any other object, for that matter) without writing a loop, you can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). This will output the whole object in JSON format, optionally indenting it.

For example:

```
console.info(JSON.stringify([{a:1,b:2}, {c:3,d:4}], null, '  '))
```

will output:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  {
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I use this method now daily for a long time to dump out all the objects and arrays :)

Comment: @andypaxo what's the diff between console.log and console.info ?

Answer (score 34):

`console.table()`does a great job of [displaying arrays neatly](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/11/13/advanced-javascript-debugging-with-consoletable) in a table format.

Comment: I am currently using this. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if you know this yet but...
Click in the triangles and you can see the complete object I think this is very practical.

---

edit

Ok sorry I dont read this part '=.= but you can check the [console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API) of firebug the chrome console supports 
[Chrome Dev Tools: Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

Comment: OP has already stated, "I modify an array I have to click on all entries to see the values"

Comment: @Jashwant +1 for paying attention! :)